# unwanted site name in url

Tags: uri, redirection, .htaccess

I've just copied my drupal website from local to server, everything is fine except the url of the site is http://www.mydrupalsite.com/mydrupalsite.com/index.php (although there is no folder named mydrupalsite.com)

The server directories and files are like this:

- root

  - .htaccess
  - mydrupalsite.com

    - index.php
    - other drupal files...
    - .htaccess (drupal one)
  - myothersite.com

    - ...

I don't think the root htaccess file has something to do with it, because myothersite.com has no problems with it. Is it possible that the .htaccess file of the drupal is causing it? If so, how to prevent it?

I made some changes and tried this in root .htaccess, but it still doesn't work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions MaxRedirects=2
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+).([a-zA-Z0-9-]+).([a-zA-Z]+)$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(.*)redirect=1(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%2.%3/$1?redirect=1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

To sum it up, I found out that this structure has been created by previous admin and should not be changed (as there are two domains). I guess the problem could be solved by removing the /mydrupalsite.com/ when present in url with .htaccess somehow, but finally I've been said it does not matter, so I left it as it is.

Comment: Check sites/default/settings.php...do you have a `$base_url` defined in there? If so, set it to a blank string

Comment: @Clive Answers man! ;]

Comment: @Clive I guess that is the answer. `;)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The $base_url is not defined there, and when I tried to set it to a blank string, I got two notices about undefined index and offset in drupal_settings_initialize(). Yes, the site in url disappears, but drupal can't find any page (only when I add the site to url again).

Comment: I notice that you say that there is no folder called mydrupalsite.com, but in your directory listing, you show mydrupalsite.com... it seems to me that your virtual host is probably pointing your domain to root and not to mydrupalsite.com

Comment: Yes, sorry, there actually is a directory named mydrupalsite.com, but I thought that when entering website mydrupalsite.com, the content of this folder is shown, so no other folders 'mydrupalsite.com' should be displayed. Yes, it is probably pointing to root, but how can I redirect it to mydrupalsite.com instead? Or is it possible to hide /mydrupalsite.com/ while browsing?

Comment: See SebCorbin's answer that should sort it. @kiam I wasn't too sure if it was the answer to be honest. I spent a lot of time on SO before using this site so I'm wary of checking before answering...they downvote you like a shot over there, not good for the self-esteem ;)

Comment: Did you create that directory structure, or was it created for you from some tools, and you cannot change it? @Clive On SO you aren't the top user. `:)` Anyway, I was not serious, before: Effectively, it was too early to answer to this question. Basing on the answer I get on my question here, users can decide on which answer better suits this question.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, and given the directory structure, you'll want to modify the .htaccess (the one in the root directory) so that requests are rewritten.

To do so, find and modify (or add) the following line:

`RewriteBase /mydrupalsite.com`

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I've tried it, but nothing has changed.

Comment: I may have been fast giving this advice:

Comment: Actually this question has already been answered here :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716839/how-to-remove-drupal-from-url-in-drupal-7-when-installation-is-in-the-associate

Answer (score 0):

If http://www.mydrupalsite.com, and http://www.myothersite.com are two domains that point to the same web server, you can set a multi-site configuration.

A multi-site configuration allows you to run Drupal on two different domains that point to the same web server copying the Drupal files in a single directory. Basing on the domain name used when accessing the site, Drupal will use a different settings.php file, which means the sites can also use different databases.
If you install Drupal on the document root directory of the web server, your sites will appear at http://www.mydrupalsite.com, and http://www.myothersite.com, without any additional paths.

I actually used a multi-site configuration for my site: Instead of having two copies of the files for the main domain, and its subdomain, I have a single copy of the files. In my case, I simply added a DNS entry to point blogs.mysite.com to mysite.com. (I have used an A entry, as I am using a static IP.)

See [Multi-site how-tos including videos](http://drupal.org/node/43816) for more information.